# java applets are blocked in browsers latest version

Tags: java, swing, browser, applet

JAVA applications(applets) which are working in old versions of firefox browser upto 47 but the same code is not working in newest version of firefox like 50+. This code is also not working in latest version of other browsers. Kindly help on this how to fix the issue.

Comment: Applets are deprecated, most browsers actively block the Applet plugin

Comment: *Kindly help on this how to fix the issue* Use modern technology

Comment: Applets have been deprecated for nearly a decade now.  You should thus not be using them at all, for any reason.

Comment: [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web)

Comment: More recent update as of 2018-03: [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) (Oracle white-paper). Applet phase-out is accelerating. More importantly, [*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) is being phased out as well. Oracle recommends moving to apps bundled with a JVM rather than relying on any JVM being installed by itself on the host machine. By the way, for web apps built with Java on the server-side but web-standards tech in the client, see [*Vaadin Framework*](http://www.Vaadin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> Kindly help on this how to fix the issue.

Move the functionality to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), and any rendering to an HTML 5 [`canvas`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/canvas).

---

Applets are dead. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for details.